# jQuery code lags for certain user opacity

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation, opacity, lag

I've a little problem with my jQuery code. I have a background with multiple preloaded image.
I want the background to switch between these images in a certain time.
Example:

Image 1 fade in as background
Fade out to black after 15s
Image 2 fade in as background
Fade out to black after 15s
etc.

But the problem is that on Chrome, there are some very short lags, and my visitors don't really like it. (Example, if we were writing on a textarea box, it freezes for half a second during the fading out to black).

Here's the code:

```
var bgs = shuffle(["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png"]);
var actualBG = -1;
var endBG = bgs[bgs.length-1]; // "image3.png"

function changeBackground()
{
    if(actualBG == -1) // If it's the first time we fade in a background
    {
        $(".bg")
            .css({'background-image': 'url('+bgs[0]+'")'})
            .animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
        setTimeout(changeBackground, 8000);
        actualBG++;
    } else {
        if(actualBG == endBG) // If we reached the end of the array
            actualBG = 0; // Go back to first slot
        else
            actualBG++; // Otherwise load the next background image

        $(".bg").animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
            $(this)
                .css({'background-image': 'url('+bgs[actualBG]+')'})
                .animate({opacity: 1});
        });
        setTimeout(changeBackground, 15000);
    }
}
```

Note: this problem doesn't occurs on Firefox, but it does on Chrome.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please also mention in your question the version of Chrome and jQuery that you are using, so that we can try and reproduce these lags.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.8.0 (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js) and latest version of Chrome. ( 24.0.1312.57 m )

Comment: Up! Still got this problem...